# PyInstaller ImportError DLL not found when testing EXE on other computer

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I built an EXE file from a Python script using PyInstaller, using

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

Packages I used:

```
pandas, numpy, imutils, opencv, logging, os, random, json, string, csv, datetime, uuid
```

The EXE runs fine on my PC. However, when I try it on another PC I get the error shown in this screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/msZrURL4v

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: In this [issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1840) the community suggest to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=14632)

Comment: as far as i know, python has two different dependency types. one is that you can include a library that is installed on your computer globally that allows you to keep one copy of the library for different python codes on your pc. the second one is that you keep a copy of library within your repo so when you create an executable, it does not require running pc to have all these dependencies installed.

Comment: My opinion ***"you try call built-in/system-wide library as external library"***. `Portable` and `built-in`  totally different things. Some package got `performance` issue (so can't port/share to another application directly), can you imagine "how your application handle sym-links/mem-alloc on all imported modules ?".If you don't have a performance problem, you can use the generic DLL library. You cannot run your program on another computer without any system analysis. Libraries that can create problems: ***pandas, numpy, imutils, opencv***

Comment: You can overcome these problems by using ctypes (causing a very serious loss of performance). You can create a DLL and insert it into all nonworking modules. I know it's annoying, but I can't think of another way to minimize the dependencies.

Comment: @dsgdfg Thanks for the reply. Could you tell me exactly what it is I need to do? I'm not sure how to do what you just said.

Comment: This is common error in Windows OS. Try and install Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable Package. Choose correct version compatible to your python version. This will solve the issue. Worked for me.

Comment: @vdvaxel There should have been a text file generated when you ran `pyinstaller` to freeze your code that contains a list of  suspected missing modules. Could you please include the contents of that file.

Comment: there is some dependency need to be installed first. make a requirement.txt file n install those from background

Answer (score 0):

The error you post just says "I was looking for one specific DLL and did not find it".

Rather than installing other packages and extensions that might, or might not, be or somehow contain the right DLL, you now need to determine exactly what it is that isn't to be found.

I can suggest three complementary methods, none absolutely certain to pinpoint the exact problem (of course the voodoo method of "install some package at random and see whether it fixes it" might also work, and often does -- but that's magic, not computer science):

- the quickest: check the pyimod03_importers.py file at line 714, see what it was doing when the exception was thrown. Due to Windows' library loading strategies, you might be handed a red herring, with a file reported not to be there when it actually is, because it relies on a second missing file whose name you won't be told.
- the easiest: use a tool like SysInternals' DEPENDS.EXE to inspect the OMR.EXE file. This is almost guaranteed not to work in this case, because the needed imports might be specified in Python format, not in any form that DEPENDS.EXE will recognize.
- the most comprehensive, but least easy: use a tool like SysInternals' PROCMON, set up the filters to exclude the background noise of Windows' idle state - there will be an awful lot of that - and then fake running OMR.EXE; exclude the additional noise generated by that. You'll need about fortyish filters to be set up. Finally run OMR.EXE. Near the end, you will see a series of attempt to load SOMETHING.DLL, all failed; the first is where the DLL is supposed to be (by either Python or OMR), the others are all suitable alternatives.

Then:

- if the DLL is one of yours, find out how to pack them with the EXE bundle.
- if it is not, you need to reliably assess where it can be found.

  - It might well be that the suggestion you were given - install MSVC redistributable that-version-or-other - was absolutely correct. Libraries with names like MSVCnn... belong to that package. MSO... files usually belong to Microsoft Office redistributables. MSJET... files are found in several Microsoft package, for example the .NET redistributable.
  - otherwise, Google and possibly MSDN Search Engine are your friends.

From past experience, I suggest setting up a virtual machine for testing, then seeing what packages are needed. This is because the first DLL crash will hide any subsequent ones, and you might need to repeat the above steps several times. The fact that the first library you need is supplied by the NETFX64 package and the second by the Microsoft Office runtime might be true, but when you find out that the second library is needed, you might also find out that the MSO runtime would have supplied the first also; so at that point, and not before, you discover that the NETFX64 package wasn't really needed, and can simplify your installation requirements to the MSO runtime alone.

Boiling down the requirements to a short list might be a lengthy task and you will want to restart the machine from scratch more than once. With a VM, that is easy to do.

(I've kept referring to the MSO runtime because I figure that your program will process a checkbox answers module, and will likey need or believe it needs some scanner recognition features, which the MSO runtime supplies. If that is so, they'll probably come last).